# trying to ban all but only attempting to ban the bot executing

Tags: discord.py

I'm making a ban all function for proof of concept but whenever I execute it, the code only attempts to ban the bot that is running the command (and fails) and doesn't ban anyone one else, no error message either.
code:

```
async def ban(ctx):
        await ctx.message.delete()
        print(f"{colorama.Fore.CYAN}[+]{colorama.Fore.YELLOW} beginning test\n")
        print(f"{colorama.Fore.CYAN}[+]{colorama.Fore.YELLOW} Banning has begun.\n")

        try:
            for member in ctx.guild.members:
                await member.ban()
                print(f"{colorama.Fore.CYAN}Smited {colorama.Fore.YELLOW}{member}.")
        except:
            print(f"{colorama.Fore.CYAN}Unable to ban {colorama.Fore.YELLOW}{member}.")
            pass
```

Comment: have you enabled members intent?

Answer (score 0):

Place your `try` statement around the `ban` function rather than around the `for loop`

```
async def ban(ctx):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    print(f"{colorama.Fore.CYAN}[+]{colorama.Fore.YELLOW} beginning test\n")
    print(f"{colorama.Fore.CYAN}[+]{colorama.Fore.YELLOW} Banning has begun.\n")

    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        try:
            await member.ban()
            print(f"{colorama.Fore.CYAN}Smited {colorama.Fore.YELLOW}{member}.")
        except:
            print(f"{colorama.Fore.CYAN}Unable to ban {colorama.Fore.YELLOW}{member}.")
            continue
```

Comment: ive tried this and im still getting the same output, "unable to ban (bot)" then not attempting to ban anyone else